# Deriving Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Derive a linear differential equation for $v(t) = z(t) \overline{z(t)} = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$ where $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t).$

I start by taking the derivative of this equation, $$v'(t)= \frac{d}{dt} x(t)^2+\frac d {dt} y(t)^2 =2x(t)x'(t)+y(t)y'(t)$$ I am not sure where to go from here.

Also, the beginning of the problem gave a real linear system $x'=a(t)x-b(t)y$ and $y'=b(t)x+a(t)y$ and it reduces to the complex linear differential equation $z'=c(t)z$ where $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$ and $c(t)=a(t)+ib(t)$